# VSTS - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops

I am trying to compile a solution on Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), using the hosted agent. One of the projects in the solution has a Pre-build event:

```
cmd /c $(SolutionDir)Tools\GenerateResourceLibrary\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\GenerateResourceLibrary.exe $(ProjectDir)
```

This command is used to generate a resource file (.resx).

Everything works as expected locally, and it was working fine on VSTS until a few weeks ago. At the moment I can't compile the solution, error message is the following:

> The system cannot find the path specified

I've checked the logs on the build server, both the tool path (`GenerateResourceLibrary.exe`) and the `$(ProjectDir)` seem to be correct. Also, I've tried changing the command slightly (putting quotes, etc) but nothing seems to work.

I was just wondering what might have changed on the hosted agent, given that this was working fine until a few weeks ago. Maybe it's a permissions issue?

Comment: You can share detail build log and build definition here

Comment: Could you share detail build log and the code of generating resource file here?

Comment: Can you still see this issue now?

Comment: Hi @Eddie-MSFT, still no luck :(

Comment: Can you share the detailed logs with "System.Debug" variable set to "true"?

Comment: Hi @Eddie-MSFT, you can find the log here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApTe4_Wkn4bJgSd_DPHIBGKOqWI-

Comment: According to the logs, "GenerateResourceLibrary.exe" was generated later than pre build event.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT that is really strange, dependencies seem to be fine. Everything runs fine locally and it was running fine on VSTS as well, until a few weeks ago.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I was finally able to fix this issue, see my answer. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to find a workaround - thanks to @Eddie and @starain who pointed me in the right direction.

The strange thing is that the project seems to have the right dependencies because it compiles successfully locally. But, as mentioned by Eddie,  `GenerateResourceLibrary.exe` was generated later than pre-build event. In order to fix this I added a task that compiles the `GenerateResourceLibrary` project **before** trying to compile the solution.

Task was configured as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure current project depends on GenerateResourceLibrary project.

Right click on your solution=>Properties=>Project Dependencies=>Select your project=>Check the option of GenerateResourceLibrary project.

Comment: Hi, I checked that. The project has the right dependencies otherwise it wouldn't compile locally. This is something that was working fine until a few weeks ago and suddenly stopped working, I wonder if it's something related to permissions on the build server? ...

Comment: @RuiJarimba It is working fine me. Could you share build log here or on the OneDrive? Also provide the detail code that used to generate resource file.

Comment: Hi @starain-MSTF, you can find the build log here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApTe4_Wkn4bJgSY8hx5xKiFau6Si   

I'm afraid I can't share the code that is used to generate the resource file :(

Comment: @RuiJarimba It seems that the issue is in that exe file, this is my simple code, you can try to generate a txt file and try again. (https://1drv.ms/t/s!AresBGZVYryjhSBjJvhaCq1DgJ2e)

Comment: I was finally able to fix this issue, see my answer. Thanks a lot for the help!